# String.Replace doesn't replace Arabic Letters

Tags: c#, string, replace, utf-8

I want to search for some text in my Arabic text, and replace it with html tag to highlight it ( Asp.net using c#) , I have this code:

```
 DocText = DocText.Replace( 
              sent.QuerySentence.Trim(), 
              string.Format(@" <span alt='{4} <hr> <p>نسبة التشابه مع جملة المصدر {6}</p> <hr>النص الأصلي : <br>{5}'   class='hightlight showTip' style='background-color:{0}' id='{1}'>{2}</span><i class=""number"">{3}</i>", 
                           restitleColor, ResultNo, sent.QuerySentence.Trim(), ResultCount, 
                           Server.HtmlDecode(DocResults.ResultsList[i].URL), 
                           sent.OriginalSentence,sent.Similarity.ToString("p")
              )
           );
```

where

```
sent.QuerySentence.Trim()
```

is part of the original text, but in my case it highlights some text, other text is not highlighted, I think the problem is with right to left, or with spacial characters like '?', I checked my code, some text was found, some other text is not found. any idea about utf-8 character replacement in c# ? thanks

Comment: .NET has no issues with arabic characters, nor does it use UTF8 internally. All strings are Unicode. `?` characters aren't special, they are the *error* character that appears when you try to read ASCII text using the wrong encoding. Where does `DocText` come from and how are you reading it?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think that would drastically increase your chances of getting a useful answer. A minimal example would only consist on *one simple* String.Replace call (without any other method calls) that reliably demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `string.Replace` is case and accent sensitive. Are you sure that's good enough to handle the replacements you need to do? Perhaps using regular expressions would be a better idea?